# Need some inputs in feature extraction in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, feature-extraction

I am new to Apache Spark and we are trying to use the MLIB utility to do some analysis. I collated some code to convert my data into features and then apply a linear regression algorithm to that. I am facing some issues . Please help and excuse if its a silly question

My person data looks like

1,1000.00,36
2,2000.00,35
3,2345.50,37
4,3323.00,45

Just a simple example to get the code working

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

case class Person(rating: String, income: Double, age: Int)
val persondata = sc.textFile("D:/spark/mydata/persondata.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).toDouble, p(2).toInt))

def prepareFeatures(people: Seq[Person]): Seq[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = {
  val maxIncome = people.map(_ income) max
  val maxAge = people.map(_ age) max

  people.map (p =>
    Vectors.dense(
      if (p.rating == "A") 0.7 else if (p.rating == "B") 0.5 else 0.3,
      p.income / maxIncome,
      p.age.toDouble / maxAge))
}


def prepareFeaturesWithLabels(features: Seq[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]): Seq[LabeledPoint] =
  (0d to 1 by (1d / features.length)) zip(features) map(l => LabeledPoint(l._1, l._2))

---Its working till here.
---It breaks in the below code

val data = sc.parallelize(prepareFeaturesWithLabels(prepareFeatures(people))

scala> val data = sc.parallelize(prepareFeaturesWithLabels(prepareFeatures(people)))
<console>:36: error: not found: value people
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
       val data = sc.parallelize(prepareFeaturesWithLabels(prepareFeatures(people)))
                                                                           ^
```

Please advise

Comment: Thanks Holden.. I was able to get through this and run the model. I actually did that for some Out Of Stock Prediction model. I have another issue not on how to link the prediction back to my original data set ...I just posted a new question on this. Please see if you can answer that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869479/linking-the-machine-learning-prediction-back-to-the-original-data-set

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be going in roughly the right direction but there are a few minor problems. First off you are trying to reference a value (people) that you haven't defined. More generally you seem to be writing your code to work with sequences, and instead you should modify your code to work with RDDs (or DataFrames). Also you seem to be using `parallelize` to try and `parallelize` your operation, but `parallelize` is a helper method to take a local collection and make it available as a distributed `RDD`. I'd probably recommend looking at the programming guides or some additional documentation to get a better understanding of the Spark APIs. Best of luck with your adventures with Spark.